# View getting loaded before data is received asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

Following is my ViewModel class:

```
public partial class DosAdminProductHierarchy : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public DosAdminProductHierarchy()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.GetProductList();
            //this.ProductList = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<Product>>(this.GetProductList());
            OnPropertyChanged("DepartmentList");

            if(isDataLoaded)
            {
                treeList.ItemsSource = ProductList;
                treeList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }           

        }

        private ObservableCollection<Product> dbProductList;
        private bool isDataLoaded = false;        
        public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
        {
            get
            {
                return dbProductList;
            }
            private set
            {
                dbProductList = value;
                isDataLoaded = true;
            }
        }





        private async void GetProductList()
        {
            try
            {
                IWebApiDataAdapter _webAPIDataAdapter = new DosAdminDataAdapter(); 
                List<Product> lstProd= new List<Product>();
                lstProd = await _webAPIDataAdapter.GetProductHierarchy();
                dbProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                foreach (Product prd in lstProd)
                {
                    dbProductList.Add(prd);
                }                                      

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is I want ProductList to be populated but it is not getting populated. Execution is reaching till the end of constructor even though data has not returned from WebApi, I want somehow to hold the execution or to show user something is busy till ProductList is getting populated. Please help how to achieve that.

Comment: use progress bar to show to the client its doing something.

Comment: I tried doing that but it is becoming 100% at the very begining, I am not able to control the threads.

Comment: make your `GetProduct` Method call `async` Try this thing. [ProgressBar](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) , [Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: How about having a bool (or visibility if you want to hide some stuff during it) property, and start an animation based on that. After your foreach is ended set it to false, and ofcourse your XAML animation (whatever it you make it) is just looking at this boolean.

Comment: can you provide a link where I can find an example of what you are describing? Implementing animation?

Comment: To prevent problems like this, simply let your property setters raise their own `OnPropertyChanged` events. `async` methods typically return before they're finished, so you're raising a `PropertyChangedEvent` before that property has actually been changed. That may not be your only problem though, but it's hard to tell without seeing the bindings in your xaml.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be loading data in a constructor. It violates the S principle of SOLID.

You should be using a `Command` linked to `Loaded` event or similar to load data.

You should also not be using `async void` method signatures as it hides `Exception` thrown by the method.

Your constructor is returning immediately because you are not calling `await GetProductsList()`. Your code results in the async method being executed after the constructor completes.

To solve your problem with the visibility, rather use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` on a `Binding` to `IsDataLoaded` property and make it notify when it changes value.

Comment: I could have used here NotifyTaskCompletion but I could not use that because later I am enumerating through the list to do some processing, can you help me out here?